# Servicestack Razor transforms sections into a nameless method (and throws errors)

Tags: servicestack, asp.net-mvc-5.2, servicestack-razor

I got the razor view engine working in my mvc application. first it threw an error  the viewpage should inherit from the mvc.WebPageBase. I made my own viewpage that inherits from mvc.WebViewPage. (So not the servicestack razor ViewPage!)

I had it working (I Included the buildProvider in the web.config and added the apphost razor plugin).

But now when i build a simple page:
[image]

I Get the following compiled code, with the error: `Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected`

[image]

Am i doing something wrong, do i need to inject a certain method name for sections or something?

Comment: i'm currently going through both source code of servicestack and mvc.razor to find how it all totally works. (this question was posted after a few hours of research already). If nobody can answer this question i'll try myself after some more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it's not clear if you're using MVC or [ServiceStack.Razor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Razor) you can't use both in the same Web App as if you use MVC it hijacks Razor page handling.

If you're using ServiceStack.Razor you need to inherit from ServiceStack's `ViewPage<TModel>`.

If you're using MVC then you can't use ServiceStack.Razor which shouldn't be installed. See this post for [inheriting a Custom MVC Razor View](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/01/09/razor-tip-2-inheritance-amp-configuration.aspx). Also you can try using the `@inherits` keyword to have your View Page inherit from a custom class, e.g:

```
@inherits Trancon.NextGen.Core.Web.Razor.DefaultRazorPage<ViewModelType>
```

Comment: hey mythz i have tried both (viewPages), but neither were working. im using a servicestackController with actionresult method View("viewname"); But somehow the page wont compile properly. I settup my environment to use servicestack.razor

Comment: `new RazorFormat() {PageBaseType = typeof(ViewPage)}` But the compiled class has no base type.

Comment: @joelharkes You can't try both, they're completely different implementations which can't be used together in the same Web App. If you're using MVC uninstall ServiceStack.Razor. See this post for [inheriting a Custom MVC Razor View](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/01/09/razor-tip-2-inheritance-amp-configuration.aspx). Also you can try using the `@inherits` keyword from inheriting a custom class.

Comment: We want to use servicestack.razor for its minify capabilities. What do mean can't use both? I'm trying to only the servicestack razor.

Comment: You can't use MVC and ServiceStack.Razor in the same web app. You say you're using `ServiceStackController` and `ActionResult` which are only classes you use with MVC in which case you can't use ServiceStack.Razor.

Comment: I've been trying to migrate from MVC razor to servicestack razor

Comment: I can't? Even if I would use it through services?

Comment: @joelharkes no you can't, they're incompatible. Using MVC causes conflicts with Razor Views so you can only use one or the other.

Comment: To be clear, if I install package Microsoft MVC & servicestack.razor (and use only the razor method from servicestack, servicestack razor doesn't work (because Microsoft MVC hijacks some part of the process)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125032/discussion-between-joel-harkes-and-mythz).